# Haskell Polymorphism

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, operator-overloading

`data Set a = Set [a]`

```
-- Example 1
instance (Eq a, Ord a)  => Eq (Set a) where 
  (Set xs) == (Set ys) = (sort xs) == (sort ys) 

-- Example 2 
instance (Eq a, Ord a)  => Eq (Set a) where   
  (==) = eqSet

eqSet (Set xs) (Set ys) = (sort xs) == (sort ys)
```

Example 1 and 2 are different ways of overriding the '==' for equality testing for the Set datatype. I'd like to know which way is preferable and why?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the difference here other than how it might get inlined or optimized.  The compiler would probably generate the same code for both, though.

Comment: Looking at the core with `-ddump-simpl`, it appears that the main difference between the two implementations is that it gets more inlined for Example 1 over Example 2, but the difference isn't even likely to matter at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference aside from the existence of the `eqSet` identifier and inlining concerns which can be solved with an `{-# INLINE eqSet #-}` pragma. My personal preference would be to use the inlined version since the separate definition doesn't provide any value, but I don't think it matters much.